# Android java math prob

Tags: java, android, math

i have the following code. Whenever try to use numbers with decimals on my app crashes.
I know is something wrong with my final result but whats wrong???

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String f = et1.getText().toString();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(f);
            String s = et2.getText().toString();
            int j = Integer.parseInt(s);
            String w = et4.getText().toString();
            int q = Integer.parseInt(s);
            int price_gold = 10;

            int fpa = 10;
            int fpol = 10;
            int isot = 10;
            int sint_ker = 10;
            Integer result1 = (i * price_gold) + (j * 1000) + (q * isot);
            result = result1 / 340;

            String res = result.toString();
            et3.setText(res);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to parse a decimal and assign it to an int.

Comment: Post logcat output because "_my app crashes_" doesn't mean much.

Comment: what i have to convert to pass it as decimal?

Comment: Use `Double` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` into `double` primitives

Comment: why doesn't he use global variables rather than creating new Variables all the time?

Comment: yes you are right... beginner here :)  whats wrong here?     <br>double result = result1 / 340.75;
    // 340.75 kanonika
    

    
    String res = result.toString();
    et3.setText(res);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have integer output as your answer, have all your values except result1 as doubles, much easier
check below:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        String f = et1.getText().toString();

        double i = Double.parseDouble(f);

        String s = et2.getText().toString();

        double j = Double.parseDouble(s);

        String w = et4.getText().toString();

        double q = Double.parseDouble(s);

        double price_gold = 10;


        double fpa = 10;

        double fpol = 10;

        double isot = 10;

        double sint_ker = 10;

        Integer result1 = ((int)i * price_gold) + ((int)j * 1000) + ((int)q * isot);

        result = result1 / 340;

        String res = String.valueOf(result);

        et3.setText(res);
    }
```

This code should then give you your integer values you are looking for, Easy :)

Comment: Accept answer if This works for you, if not tell me the errors i have here

Comment: thats it thanks. Just kept decimal result and just changed     double result1 = (i * price_gold) + (j * 1000) + (q * isot);

Comment: Nice one, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use *Float.parseFloat* but be careful of empty text, something like the following

```
String f = et1.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(f)) {
    Float i = Float.parseFloat(f);
}
```